# PyQt5: module "QtCharts" is not installed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml, qtcharts

I'm trying to use QtCharts from QML in a PyQt5 app.

Qt5 is installed via HomeBrew, and the QtCharts module appears to be installed (unless when called via PyQt5 it looks somewhere else):

```
$ ls -1 /usr/local/opt/qt5/qml/QtCharts
designer
libqtchartsqml2.dylib
plugins.qmltypes
qmldir
```

In PyQt5, I can run a QtQuick app without problems, but if I try to `import QtCharts 2.2` I get an error:

> module "QtCharts" is not installed

Minimal testcase that exhibits this problem:

*test_qml_qtcharts.py*

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlEngine()
component = QQmlComponent(engine)
component.setData(b'''
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtCharts 2.2
Item {}
''', QUrl('main.qml'))
instance = component.create()

if not instance:
    for error in component.errors():
        print(error.toString())
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test_qml_qtcharts.py
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
main.qml:3:1: module "QtCharts" is not installed
```

Removing `import QtCharts 2.2` the test runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong assuming it would look into the system's Qt5 installation.

Solution: install PyQtChart via pip:

```
python3 -m pip install PyQtChart
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Even after pip installation, the issues persist. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks in advance.